# Logo instead of application title Shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, navbar, tabpanel

How can I put instead of title in Shiny app:

```
navbarPage("title",theme = shinytheme("flatly"), 
                   tabPanel("Home",
```

some logo in the size of menu tab?
I tried this solution:
[How can I insert an image into the navbar on a shiny navbarPage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705431/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-the-navbar-on-a-shiny-navbarpage)
but someway is not working. Image too big overlay all menu items

Thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an old question but I was looking for a solution and the other ones I found caused issues when I tried to publish my application using shinyapps.io and this was due to the fact that I was using both `fluidPage` and `navbarPage` as suggested in other answers.

Here is my solution which I recieved from the support team at shinyapps.io

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ LOGAN SERVICES DASHBOARD ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(#the line of code places the logo on the left hand side before the tabs start. See image below.
                        title = div(img(src='LoganTogether-LOGO.jpg',
                        style="margin-top: -14px;
                               padding-right:10px;
                               padding-bottom:10px",
                        height = 60)),
                        #theme = "journal",
                        windowTitle="Logan Together: Service Map",

                        #MAIN TAB~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                       
                        tabPanel("Interactive map", # then you go on to code the rest of your UI as normal
```

[image]