# Insert Figure in shiny navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny, shinythemes

Friends could help me insert a figure into my shiny navbarPage. I would like to remove the written word "Simulation" in my navbarPage and insert the attached figure instead. Is this possible to do in shiny? any help is appreciated. The executable code is below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinytables)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
              "Simulation", 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 20,
                    value = 30),
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
    )
  )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much!

[image]

#### Insertion this code

```
ui <- shiny::navbarPage(
  
  title = div(img(src='simulation.jpg',style="margin-top: -14px; padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px", height = 60)),
  windowTitle="Simulation",
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logo instead of application title Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219885/logo-instead-of-application-title-shiny)

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't. I inserted above the code that was inserted as well as the image. Do you have any idea what the error could be?

Comment: I saw the error friend is in the src. How do I find the directory to place the images on the src?

Comment: You should place the image in a www folder as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21998722/13473361). You may also need to split the app.R file in the ui.R and the server.R files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
shinyUI(
    navbarPage(title = div("", img(src = "simulation.jpg", id = "simulation", height = "50px",width = "100px",style = "position: relative; margin:-15px 0px; display:right-align;")), 
               theme = shinytheme("flatly"), 
               tabPanel("Simulation",collapsible = TRUE,
                        sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                                sliderInput("bins",
                                            "Number of bins:",
                                            min = 1,
                                            max = 50,
                                            value = 30)
                            ),

                            sidebarLayout(
                                sidebarPanel(
                                    sliderInput("bins",
                                                "Number of bins:",
                                                min = 1,
                                                max = 20,
                                                value = 30)
                                ),
                                mainPanel(
                                    plotOutput("distPlot")
                                )
                            )
                        ))
    )

)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes friend, which directory did you insert this image for the shiny search?

Comment: its in www folder where `ui.R` and `server.R` are

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Pork Chop, Could you tell me how I find this ```www ``` that you showed above?, I didn't find it. I did it via website link. But I was wondering what the exact directory is to find this ```www```. For example: C:/Users /Documents/R/...........

Comment: You create that directory yourself where the server.r and ui.r are