# How to place an image in an R Shiny title

Tags: r, shiny

So I am using R Shiny and I want to place an image to the right of the text in the title. I can seem to place the image anywhere in the application with the exception of next to the title. Can you not place images in the `titlePanel()` function? Here is a snippet of the code that I am using:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for random distribution application 
shinyUI(fluidPage(#theme="bootstrap.css",

  # Application title
  titlePanel("My Title",img(src = "picture.jpg", height = 50, width = 100)),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
```

So when I use the above code I can't seem to see my image anywhere in the app....

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One way would be to follow the directions in this post: [How can I insert an image into the navbar on a shiny navbarPage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705431/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-the-navbar-on-a-shiny-navbarpage) (The SO hounds would attack this as a duplicate).

Create a folder called 'www' in your working directory and place 'picture.jpg' inside as so:

```
| shinyApp/
    | ui.R
    | server.R
 | www/
    | picture.png
```

Include your picture in titlePanel with a div:

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for random distribution application 
shinyUI(fluidPage(#theme="bootstrap.css",

  # Application title
  titlePanel(title=div(img(src="picture.jpg"), "My Title")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    )
  )
)
)
```

[image]