# Embedding an image in a table cell using DT, R and Shiny not working

Tags: r, shiny, dt

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671958/how-to-embed-an-image-in-a-cell-a-table-using-dt-r-and-shiny) and it was answered. However, now, it is not working for me. I am not sure if there is any changes in the package. Any ideas?

### ui.r

```
require(shiny)
library(DT)

 shinyUI(
  DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
 )
```

### server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


dat <- data.frame(
    country = c('USA', 'China'),
    flag = c('<img src="http://flaglane.com/download/american-flag/american-
            flag-large.png" height="52"></img>',
            '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/Flag_of_China.png" height="52"></img>'
 )
 )

  shinyServer(function(input, output){
   output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(dat, escape = FALSE)
  })
})
```

### Edits

My feeling was if it does not work in the Rstudio viewer, it would not work when I launch Shiny. However, I was wrong. When I run the app it works fine but in Rstudio Viewer, it does not.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


  dat <- data.frame(
  country = c('USA', 'China'),

  flag = c('<img src="http://flaglane.com/download/american-flag/american-
    flag-large.png" height="52"></img>',
       '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/Flag_of_China.png" height="52"></img>'
  )
   )
DT::datatable(dat, escape = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is incomplete. Does this work?

```
require(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(
  DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
)

dat <- data.frame(
  country = c('USA', 'China'),
  flag = c('<img src="http://flaglane.com/download/american-flag/american-flag-large.png" height="52"></img>',
           '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/Flag_of_China.png" height="52"></img>'
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(dat, escape = FALSE)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It works fine for me.

Comment: Does it also work if you download the image first to your machine? It is not working for me. Thanks

Comment: That should work yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182535/how-to-place-an-image-in-an-r-shiny-title. Make sure the image is in the right folder.

Comment: Thanks! The key point is putting it in "www/" folder not "data/" folder

Comment: @FissehaBerhane You said you figuer how to run it locally, can you post the code you used because I change the image to the www folder and it doesn´t show up

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade: I used it in my blog . See if it helps: http://datascience-enthusiast.com/R/Modals_data_exploration_Shiny.html

Comment: @FissehaBerhane Thanks