# Inserting image on the far-right side navbarPage shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code for a shiny app generating a navbarPage

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Report", theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  tabPanel("About"),
  tabPanel(
    "Plots",
    fluidPage(
      tabsetPanel(
        type = "pills",
        tabPanel("A"),
        tabPanel(
          "B",
          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(h4("Checkbox"),
              checkboxInput("total", label = "total"),
              uiOutput("conditionalInput"),
              width = 3
            ),
            mainPanel(
              tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("a"),
                tabPanel("b"),
                tabPanel("c"),
                tabPanel("d"),
                tabPanel("e")
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  output$conditionalInput <- renderUI({
    if (input$total == FALSE) {
      checkboxGroupInput("verticais",
        label = "",
        choices = list(
          "1.1" = 1,
          "1.2" = 2,
          "1.3" = 3,
          "1.4" = 4,
          "1.5" = 5,
          "1.6" = 6,
          "1.7" = 7,
          "1.8" = 8
        ),
        selected = c(1:8), inline = FALSE
      )
    }
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Which produces this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9ZGo.jpg)

However, for layout purposes, I want to put a logo on the far right side of the window (near where the publish button is). 
I tried what is described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705431/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-the-navbar-on-a-shiny-navbarpage) with no success.

Therefore, I want to know if there is another workaround to solve my problem.

Note that I have the image files on the correct www folder

Comment: Please include reproducible example

Comment: Could you be more clearer? I sincerely do not know what is lacking so you (or anyone else) can help me resolve my issue.

Comment: Please include at least a code that runs (without `...`) with what you have tried

Comment: The css answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996887/embedding-image-in-shiny-app) may help. I don't see how else you can do it without css

Comment: @waterling couldn't get that to work, but I'll keep trying. I also edited the question to contain a reproducible example.

Comment: I got a workaround by changing the `navbarPage` piece of code to `navbarPage(title = div("Report", img(src = "myimage.png", height = "10px", style = "position: relative; top: -3px; right: -1000px;")), theme = shinytheme("cerulean")` It is still not the best since the image does not attach to the navbar and also creates an unnecessary empty space between the title and the tabsets.

Comment: @luizgg please submit your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got a workaround by changing the `navbarPage` piece of code to:

```
navbarPage(title = div("Report",
                       img(src = "myimage.png",
                           height = "10px",
                           style = "position: relative;
                                    top: -3px;
                                    right: -1000px;")),
           theme = shinytheme("cerulean")
```

It is still not the best since the image does not attach to the navbar and also creates an unnecessary empty space between the title and the tabsets.