# Placing an image on right end of navigation bar in navbarPage() layout in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm looking to replicate a similar layout as RStudio's SuperZip Shiny dashboard available here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html

The code for that app is available here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/063-superzip-example

Based off that code, I would like to add an image on the right end of the navigation bar (let's say the Rstudio logo), highlighted with the red box in the image below. I assume I'd need to add some HTML and CSS code but I'm unsure on how to proceed.

[image]

My question is similar to this question: [How can I insert an image into the navbar on a shiny navbarPage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705431/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-the-navbar-on-a-shiny-navbarpage)

However, note that the answer provided an indication on putting an image on the LEFT END of the navigation bar. I'm asking to have it on the RIGHT END of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The linked solution is probably not gonna work for placing the logo on the right. I would suggest using some `JavaScript` code to `append` the logo to the `navbar`.

**Solution**:

1. Create the `JS` file (I named my file `code.js`)

When the app is finished loading, it's gonna append the logo to the navbar. (Image is aligned to the right)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".navbar .container-fluid" ).append( '<img src="logo.png" align="right">' );
});
```

2. Place the logo (in my case `logo.png`) and the `JS` file inside the `www` folder.
3. Include the js file in `tags$head`

You need to use `tagList` with `navbarPage` because otherwise a clickable "ghost" tab would appear on the navbar.

```
ui <- tagList(
  tags$head(tags$script(type="text/javascript", src = "code.js")),
  navbarPage(title = "Right aligned logo",
             tabPanel("tab1"),
             tabPanel("tab2")
  )
)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I have trouble with this approach if I also include `tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}")` in the `tagList` to make sure my nav bar doesn't overlap with the content. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: How is the `navbar` overlapping with the content? You should maybe post a new question on SO with a reproducible example.

Comment: If you use `position = "fixed-top"`, then the navbar will overlay the content. It's in the `navbarPage` help file. I think this is related to and can improve this answer since many people would use this option.

Comment: Okay, now I see. In that case you could add: `tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", ".tab-content {padding-top: 70px;}"))`

Comment: unable to reproduce this. I have files ( js and .png)  in www folder. Not sure what I am missing here, can you re-check this ? Also, is there any shinyjs package solution ? I get this browser error "The script from “http://127.0.0.1:584/custom.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) "

Comment: @GyD can i add hyperlink to the logo?

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, you can. Instead of `.append( '<img src="logo.png" align="right">' );` you can include the `img` in an `a` (link) tag, like this: `.append( '<a href="http://google.com"><img src="logo.png" align="right"></a>' );`

Answer (score 2):

I got some help elsewhere, and I'm posting it here:

In the ui.R code:

```
navbarPage(
  title = div(
    div(
      id = "img-id",
      img(src = "path/to/img.png")
    ),
    "Superzip"
  ),

  # Insert rest of ui code
```

In the `styles.css` script:

```
#img-id{
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: It's a great solution, except it doesn't remove the ghost tab after the `tabPanel`s, see: https://imgur.com/a/mucZD

Comment: I just checked on my work computer, and I don't see the ghost tab now (Maybe it was my mistake...). The only issue remaining with this solution is that the `title` showing in the browser is gonna be `<div ...>` which is kind of ugly, otherwise I would probably prefer this over using js.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do prefer your answer as I think it is more generalized.

Comment: You can update the title with: `jsTitleChange <- 'Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("changetitle", function(x) {document.title=x});` and then `session$sendCustomMessage("changetitle", "new title")` so it doesn't look ugly on the browser.