# Static image (png) in R Shiny navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny, png

I'm struggling to display a logo (`logo.png`) in the `navbarPage` of an R Shiny app. I followed the advice/instructions I found in the internet (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705431/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-the-navbar-on-a-shiny-navbarpage), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219885/logo-instead-of-application-title-shiny), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151766/adding-images-in-the-title-and-at-the-right-of-navbarpage) or [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/adding-images-in-the-title-and-at-the-right-of-navbarpage/52302/3) and even [here](https://groups.google.com/g/shiny-discuss/c/4LiXloXyeGU)) and in principle, it seems to work. At least the title appears and the padding is respected. However, only a placeholder is shown instead of the actual png and if you view the image it says "Not Found":

[image]

The structure of the app is as follows:

```
global.R
ui.R
server.R
www/img/logo.png
```

The code (located in `ui.R`):

```
shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    title = div(img(src = "logo.png",
                    filetype = "image/png",
                    style = "margin-top: -14px;
                            padding-right: 20px;
                            padding-bottom: 10px"),
                "Title",
    tabPanel("Some",
             ...),
    ...
    )
)
```

I have the suspicion that the issue is somehow related to the structure of the Shiny app (I also tried with the full path of the logo `www/img/logo.png` without success), but I fail to figure out where.

Would be great if anyone could give me some advice or hint. Thank you :)

Comment: try `img/logo.png`

Comment: Indeed! It shows now :) But the layout is distorted, everything flushed to random places... :( Still, thank you!

Comment: you may want to play with the CSS

Comment: I solved the positioning with html (see below). Can you maybe post your first comment as answer so that I can accept it? :)

To place the logo left, insert this lines after `img(...)`:
```tags$script(HTML("var header = $('.navbar > .container-fluid');
                  header.append('<div style=\"float:right\"><ahref=\"URL\"><img src=\"img/logo-ioew.png\" alt=\"logo\" style=\"float:right;width:auto;height:43px;padding-top:10px;\"> </a>`</div>');
                                   console.log(header)")```

Comment: sure, I also added some details.

Comment: Great, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defaults, Shiny uses `www` as root for internet resources. So, if you have an image stored in `working_path/www/img/img.png`, the right path will be `img/img.png`.

If you want to specify other paths, use `addResourcePath()`

e.g. If you want to show an image under `my_path/img/img.png` you want first add the path

```r
addResourcePath("new_root", "my_path")
```

Then refer it in Shiny as

```r
img(src = "new_root/img/img.png")
```