# R Shiny Use image instead of navbar title

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to use an image instead of the title in the navbar of my Shiny-Web-App.
An example was discussed and solved in this post:
[How can I insert an image into the navbar on a shiny navbarPage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705431/how-can-i-insert-an-image-into-the-navbar-on-a-shiny-navbarpage)

However, it does not work in my case. I can't explain why either.
Here you can see my reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = div(img(
    src = "proxy-image.png",
    height = 20,
    width = 20,
    style = "margin:1px 1px"
  ), "My title"),
  collapsible = FALSE,
  theme = bslib::bs_theme()
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also added my image in the .png-format here:
[image]

My result looks like this:

[image]

Can someone help me to solve my problem?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: where is the png file relative to the app.R file? Putting the image in a `www` folder in the same directory as the R file might be the last step needed.

Comment: The png file ist in the same folder of der app.R file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key things are to a) have your image files (and other external media such as css) in a `www` folder, and b) run using RStudio's 'Run App' button or using `shinyAppDir(getwd())` command (to run in working directory).

So your file structure (as an RStudio project) should look like:

```
.
├── app.R
├── test_app.Rproj
└── www
    └── proxy-image.png
```